# Show that the straight line $\overleftrightarrow{DC}$ is the polar to point C

Tags: geometry, circles

Consider a circle $K=(O,k)$, and two points $A, B$ in the circle $K$ such that the tangents to the circle $l_A$ and $l_B$ at $A$ and $B$ respectively intersect at a point $C$. Let $D$ be third point on the circle $K$ such that its tangent $l_D$ intersects the line $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ at $E$.

Prove that the line $\overleftrightarrow{CD}$ is the polar of $E$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint.* Use [La Hire’s Theorem](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/LaHire.shtml): $CD$ is the polar of $E$ if and only if $E$ lies both on the polar of $C$ and on the polar of $D$, yet the last statement is trivial.